# Unable to Wake phone and Display Activity when the phone is locked

Tags: android, wakelock, screen-lock, powermanager

I am Launching an activity from the service. I am acquiring the partial wake lock before the service is started.

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
```

I am starting the activity from service like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

In My Activity class i am adding flags to display activity when screen locked like this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    /*Code to open a Dialog*/
}
```

When i Debug all the code works fine. Activity is called successfully. But if the screen is locked (There is no secure lock keyguard) the phone screen doesn't displays the activity. I have to manually unlock the phone and then can see the activity from running applications list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED) you must also set [FLAG_FULLSCREEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_FULLSCREEN) for your activity

Comment: adding FLAG_FULLSCREEN doesn't help. still not working

Comment: Along with the flags setting **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"** for the activity in Manifest file made the activity visible above keyguard.